# Unpermitted parameter with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I am trying to use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but I get an `unpermitted parameters: address` when I try to create or update a field in the address model

I have a relationship between two models a Client which has an Address as follows

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
    ...

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
```

The strong parameters are set up according to this http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
as follows

```
  def client_params
        params.require(:client).permit(:name, :tel, :email, :website, :photo,
            address_attributes: [:id, :line1, :line2, 
            :town, :country, :zip_code])
  end
```

The update action in the controller uses `client_params`

```
def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    if @client.update(client_params)
    ...
```

the form uses `form_for` and `field_for`

```
form_for :client, url: path, method: mymethod, html: {multipart: true, role:'form'} do |f|
    = f.text_field :name
    ...
    = f.fields_for :address do |a|
        = a.text_field :line1, label: 'First line'
        = a.text_field :line2, label: 'Second line'
        = a.text_field :town
        = a.text_field :country
        = a.text_field :zip_code
```

The client fields work fine. However, if i try to update one of the address fields the address in not updated and `unpermitted parameter: address` is logged.

Here are the parameters from such a request

```
Parameters: { 
 "utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Yx+ualZcCUZTriCIiCfF1SrFVUGdOnFgWApiYqKAMXU=",
 "client"=> {
    "name"=>"Alice",
    "email"=>"",
    "tel"=>"",
    "website"=>"",
    "address"=> {
        "line1"=>"Casa 1",
        "line2"=>"",
        "town"=>"",
        "country"=>"",
        "zip_code"=>""}},
   "commit"=>"Save Details",
   "id"=>"16"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My earlier answer was mostly irrelevant. Here's what I think the problem is, the nested attributes in the params require must reference **plural** of the model name.

Where you have `address_attributes:` must be plural `addresses_attributes:`

I think that's the problem.

```
  def client_params
        params.require(:client).permit(:name, :tel, :email, :website, :photo,
            addresses_attributes: [:id, :line1, :line2, 
            :town, :country, :zip_code])
  end
```

Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Val, your example code is clearer than mine, but I can't see how the structure is different to what I have. Could you point me to what I need to change?

Comment: You're right. That's embarrassing. Sorry. Really. Let me look deeper at the rest of the code you posted. If I see something, I'll update my answer and let you know.

Comment: @cdog There was something odd about your form that I didn't catch at first. I added a section to my answer and updated the form code snippet. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @cdog Did you solve this? I kept thinking about it and I think I found something easily missed. I updated my answer. It's an easy test.

Comment: I think I have solved the issues with the strong parameters by changing the syntax for the nested attribute to :address => [...]. permit is now return the hash i am expecting.

Comment: I still not sure why I could not get this working using the syntax shown [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: @cdog As I noted in my revision, did you try the plural "addresses" in the .permit statement: addresses_attributes: [:id, :line1, :line2, :town, :country, :zip_code])? That follows the spec. To me everything else looks like it should work, only "address_attributes"  not being plural was the one thing I could see that looked wrong.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention i tried the pluralized version, but i would still not permit the address.

Comment: Actually, I am now getting this which  I think my still be related to the values be returned by permit  ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ClientsController#create
Address(#70092602683060) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70092597195800)

Comment: Looks like progress, working through the issues. A case of a  has_one relationship and accepts nested attributes should be straightforward. This problem is perplexing. Do you want to post the code around the line # that throws the error?

Comment: Two ideas: (1) Do you know why you're getting an address#create action (which throws the error) in a client#update action? Is there an address record to update? (2) Typematch error is telling you to look at the table fields and examine if you're trying to assign a string value to a number, etc. Have you confirmed the field types in address match what you're trying to create/update?

Comment: Sorry, i copied the error when i created a new record, but i get the same TypeMismatch on update. I will update the post later with some more details

Comment: An address record is not created in the first place; that's good to know. It's important to see what happens at the database level when you make the POST request to the parent client record.. Please post the development server log with the database queries and responses, through ROLLBACK.